# How can I realistically make a worldwide government that works with my fictional world with different magical races?

Tags: internal-consistency, government, interspecies-relations

#### Question

What would a world-wide "government" look like, in this world?

#### Creatures inhabiting this world

In my world, there are five magical races besides regular non-magical humans:

- Woven
- elementals
- magical beings
- mages
- witches

#### Cities and governments of my government

This world is divided (political boundary-wise) just like ours. I developed ten cities to hold the headquarters of this government (Geneva, Vienna, New York City, Nairobi, Tokyo, Singapore, Seoul, Dubai, Stockhlom, Rio de Janeiro) to keep up with this complex relationship (there are the regular countries, though natural phenomena are different) as well as the regular governments plus three governments (witches, mages, Woven) for those races, two councils (magical beings + elementals) and the real world human rights.

There are also individual governments for different types (species) of magical beings, different individual governments for regular people + witches + mages, and different governments and councils for elementals. There are four existing monarchies (two representative/puppet). There are also embassies from each of these political orginazations and countries and major orginizations in each city.

#### Political situation

All of this is regulated by this government.  The political tension is like this: There's a lot of animosity between elementals and mages because mages get their power by stealing power from elementals. Woven are neutral, magical beings and witches formed their own side. Regular humanity runs and hides under a rock when the others fight.

Mages are popular and usually the head of political orginizations. Elementals stay separate but are powerful enough (considered the most powerful) to be able to pull the "atomic bomb" threatening card. That is to say, they are powerful enough to be a real threat.

Magical organisms and witches are less respected (except for their leaders) and looked down upon by mages, but the leaders of the magical organisms are just as dangerous as the elementals. The witches are not as powerful as mages, The Woven are neutral, bargaining for peace. They are not above subterfuge and assasination: although everyone underestimates them, they are just as (sometimes more than) the elementals. Nobody seems to realize this.

#### Governments of each race

The main government for the witches is essentially a group that sets laws, restrictions, and sentences for witches, while keeping an eye on all countries to ensure witches have their full rights.

The main government for mages is the same, but the mages also have a larger political influence.

The Woven government is quite different. There are no copies of many of the Woven--the only subrace are the regular weavers, but anomaly Woven exist and are sentient. The Woven government doesn't really set laws: all Woven follow laws. But they do regulate the internet--the "World Wide Web" as it were--and the code-Woven entity underneath it. They also control the education and training of all of the weavers, and protection of the other rare Woven. They have very little political power, but make great diplomats.

The government for magical beings isn't as strict. It's essentially a council of the five greatest of the magical races (elementals and Woven not counted.) Each race has its own leader(s) and own style of government (monarchies, councils, etc.). The communal government needs the approval of every leader of every species of beings to declare war, to issue the death sentence for a crime commited against another race, and to pass a universally binding law. It's not really politically powerful other than the fact that it's made up of the five most powerful magical races.

The government for the elementals is pretty similar to that of the magical beings, with the exception that elementals don't really abide by anything other than the barest of laws. They usually don't interact with anyone besides the Woven anomalies and some magical beings. 
So, these are the separate governments for the races, in addition to the governments of countries. Now to combine their support into this government.

#### Statistics

A tiny percent of the human/human looking population is "abnormal." 7,000 weavers are currently alive (the Lesser Woven race) and there are currently 2,500 witches. Mages, though? Their population is estimated at 25,000. The Woven races and elementals have existed before all other life. Magical beings evolved before humans. And mages are mostly human, simply slightly altered by their power (while witches were once magical beings). These systems have existed forever, but not until recently had the political boundaries subsided and everything made a huge jump forwards.

#### Question

What would a worldwide government look like here? Are there any important points I should consider to apply to things like economy, human (or nonhuman) rights, religious rights (there are four cults and six religions, the religions accepted, the cults are . . weird), scientific research, war/fighting, food/water/shelter needs, pop. growth, technological development (think ten years ahead of our world), and (most importantly) diplomacy?  By structure I mean

- Hierarchical structure and main councils/committees/*I don't know what's*
- Human Rights Watch (Plus a Non-Human Rights Watch)
- The general court and law system (Including The World Court/International Court of Justice)
- Economy

I'm not talking about

- The applications of the economy/religion/rights/pop.growth+needs/all above on regular everyday life.

### This is a world government like the UN in that it acts as a diplomatic "regulation."

In terms of

## Power

1st place: **TIE**: Greater Woven/Elementals/Great Five (leaders of Magical Beings)

2nd place: Lesser Woven (weavers.)

3rd place: Other Magical Beings

4th place: **TIE**: Witches/Mages

5th place:

Puny humans who cower in fear

## Extra Info on this government

I copied some of these phrases/questions from @Green (thank you, Green)

> 1) If this governmental organization does absolutely nothing else, what must it achieve? **Peace. Relations between the governments of nations and between the governments of these races.**

and

> 2) How does this organization get its money/funding? Can it tax members or does it rely on donations? It does both. Without the ability to hurt an uncooperative member, the threat of taxation is void. **"Trade negotiations" say it all.**

---

## Pressures

The pressures to create such a diplomatic organization is simply to prevent all-out warfare and promote the well being of all living beings in all positions. Weavers are especially keen on this; and have the interests of all in mind. The magical races want to protect themselves, and the witches want to protect the magical races as well as the environment.

The pressures to disband it are from the mages (power-hungry), elementals (don't like constraints).

---

**Thank you to the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) and its users who helped me so much in shaping and pruning this question, especially [Green](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/10364/green), who was invaluable to helping me with this question in both the old Sandbox and the new.**

Comment: **Note to VTCers and Downvoters**: Please leave a detailed comment outlining why you are downvoting/VTCing this question and leave a suggestion showing how you think this issue can be fixed. Thank you for being considerate.

Comment: IMHO: (note, this is *not* an answer), I think a Global government is ludicrous at best. We cannot achieve this 'goal' with run of the mill humans, not even as a topic of discussion.   With a look at Human history, you should be aware that the "Puny Humans who cower in Fear" also built Singapore, New York, Tokyo, etc.  We Typically exterminate *any*thing/one who even appears to be a threat, including ourselves.  35,000 non-humans would be extinct in less than a year. - just my $0.02

Comment: "This world is divided (political boundary-wise) just like ours" such division seems to preclude a "world government" of any sort. You also seem to be describing separate governments based on racial divisions. Where does world government fit into this question?

Comment: @Ash World government like the UN in that it acts as a diplomatic "regulation." Will add

Comment: You keep mentioning its like the UN... why not just use the UN? You could also use the EU

Comment: @Shadowzee, in the Sandbox, I originally was asking how the structure of the UN would translate to this setting . . . I guess I'll edit that back in.

Answer (score 5):

I think your going to end up with a United Nations style of government. This would be combined with a European parliament system because no group would ever achieve a majority of votes/candidates or any other majority. Therefore each group would make temporary alliances to get laws passed. Don't discount the regular humans assuming they can contribute a large amount of labor and cash to any endeavor.

This may be much simpler than what you are looking for but it leaves plenty of opportunity for backroom deals and intrigue.

Comment: +1 I.e. not a true government but rather a reconciliation body that can keep individual governments in peace.

Comment: This seems like the direction J.K. Rowling pointed.

Answer (score 2):

As luck may have it, I also made a story in which took place in a highly interconnected/globalized fantasy world with humans on the bottom rungs on the worldwide social ladder.

I would suggest considering that nations/governments do not necessarily form around ethnic groups. The USA is a famous example of a melting pot, as we like to say, but even ancient superpowers like the Romans, pre-British India and China, and central American civilizations were a hodgepodge of different peoples.

Even under the unifying factors of species, I think your world's governments would consist of multiple species. For example, it would make sense for humans and lesser Woven to ally themselves with the elementals or mages for protection. After all, picking a side is a great way to avoid being caught in a crossfire. Apart from areas that were formally geographically isolated (like how mountain ranges protected India from a lot of outside influence and Australia/Americas were separated from the old world by a bloody great ocean) human founded and run governments might be rare.

Also, if a handful of elements can play "the atomic bomb card", every nation would try to get a few of them within their borders and/or on government payroll.

Now that that's out of the way:

1) Religion might be divided into race-religions and conversion religions.

A race religion would be any system of belief that a single race/species made up to account for their own existence, likely placing themselves at the center of the universe. These would be great at uniting a species, but would probably diminish once promises start going unfulfilled. A real-world example would be Japan's Shintoism, which became a force of nationalization during WWII and painted the Japanese as "the chosen people" and currently only exists as a few spiritual traditions.

Conversion religions would be designed to bring together people from all walks of life and, in this case, across the race/species barrier. In these narratives, all the races would be included and have the same end goal, be that the End of Days or universal harmony. Socially speaking, these religions have a lot of staying power (due to being unaffected by political developments) and are highly profitable for those in charge of them (I believe the Catholic Church are still own the most land out of any non-government body).

2) Human-ish rights would be odd.

Nowadays, its generally accepted that the worth of a person is intrinsic, but its hard to argue equality when some members of a race/species can cast fireballs. Humans might have a lot of the more menial jobs because all the other races can be put to better use than collecting garbage or flipping burgers. Still, humans and other less powerful races would *eventually* get representation simply due to meriting it. A society can only ignore oppression for so long, after all. It would be important to show how the history of conflict has shaped relations between these races, however.

2) Law would be most efficient if equal.

While I have little doubt that early legal systems would favor on race/species over another (if a elemental commits the same crime as a human, the law states the elemental gets punished less because it is objectively more valuable), I think the legal system would eventually settle on equality. Or, at least, strive toward equality. Otherwise the system would become choked by protests and warped by discrimination.

I know the above is describing current events in the United States, but FoxElemental's world would start off as being **way** more unbalanced than ours. I am being a total idealist here, by the way. Litigated segregation might be alive and well in this setting.

3) Economy would largely remained unaltered (as far as I can tell).

When it comes down to it, the transfer of goods and serves tends to ignore politics. Humans might be underpayed and mages disproportionately wealthy, but  personally can't think of any super huge economic consequences based on the given information. If magic can create something from nothing, that would be huge. If elemental don't need food or shelter, that would also impact a lot of things. If Woven inhabits areas of great mineral wealth, that might be significant.

As a whole, I wouldn't worry too much about economy. Not too many works hinge on, say, the price of bantha meat on Consonant compared to Tattooeen.

This is the best I can come up with given the information you have given me. I hope at least some of it is useful to you.